# jFreeChart no displayed in browser

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to display a jFreeChart using jsp. The chart is generated but cannot be viewed in the browser. It shows an empty frame in the browser. Is there some other configuration to be performed?

JSP page:

```
%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%@ page  import="java.awt.*" %>
<%@ page  import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.axis.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.labels.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.chart.urls.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.data.category.*" %>
<%@ page  import="org.jfree.data.general.*" %>

<%
            final double[][] data = new double[][]{
                {210, 300, 320, 265, 299},
                {200, 304, 201, 201, 340}
            };

            final CategoryDataset dataset = DatasetUtilities.createCategoryDataset(
                    "Team ", "", data);

            JFreeChart chart = null;
            BarRenderer renderer = null;
            CategoryPlot plot = null;


            final CategoryAxis categoryAxis = new CategoryAxis("Match");
            final ValueAxis valueAxis = new NumberAxis("Run");
            renderer = new BarRenderer();

            plot = new CategoryPlot(dataset, categoryAxis, valueAxis, renderer);
            plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);
            chart = new JFreeChart("Srore Bord", JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);

            chart.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(249, 231, 236));

            Paint p1 = new GradientPaint(
                    0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(16, 89, 172), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(201, 201, 244));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(1, p1);

            Paint p2 = new GradientPaint(
                    0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(255, 35, 35), 0.0f, 0.0f, new Color(255, 180, 180));
            renderer.setSeriesPaint(2, p2);

            plot.setRenderer(renderer);

            try {
                final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo(new StandardEntityCollection());
                final File file1 = new File("D:/barchart.png");
                ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                out.println(e);
            }
%>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
        <!meta  http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <IMG SRC="barchart.png" WIDTH="600" HEIGHT="400" BORDER="0" USEMAP="#chart">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First this is more a HTML question.

"d:\barchart.png" will not be the correct directory for your web server to load the image. Your IMG-reference is relative to the current page. But you place the file in root directory of drive D. You need to move the output location to some place accessible by the web browser and adjust the reference in the HTML output.

BTW.: Generating the image this may works for a single user only. Parallel access to the page may remove and recreate the image with each call. This may cause display errors with parallel access.